# .NET 6 Minimal web app for permanent redirect on Azure App Service on Linux (Applicatin error / Site reported as unsafe)

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0

I have a subdomain which must redirect any route to a main domain root:

1. http(s)://subdomain.example.com/ => *https://example.com*
2. http(s)://subdomain.example.com/{*anything} => *https://example.com*

So, I have created a minimal .NET 6 web app:

```
using System.Net;

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
{
    options.RedirectStatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.PermanentRedirect;
    options.HttpsPort = 443;
});

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

app.Urls.Add("http://+");
app.Urls.Add("https://+");

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapGet("/", () => Results.Redirect("https://example.com", true, true));
app.MapGet("/{*_}", (string _) => Results.Redirect("https://example.com", true, true));

app.Run();
```

When I run it locally, everything works:

- http://localhost redirects to *https://example.com*
- http://localhost/blah redirects to *https://example.com*
- https://localhost redirects to *https://example.com*
- https://localhost/blah redirects to *https://example.com*

Then I created App Service (Linux) in Azure for which:

- I set up my custom domain *subdomain.example.com*
- I added App Service Managed certificate for my custom subdomain
- HTTPS only is ON

Looks good so far. But when I deploy my app and run it, 2 problems:

1. opening https://mycustomapp.azurewebsites.net shows me **This site has been reported as unsafe** (!)
2. when open http(s)://subdomain.example.com I get application error

And here's what I see in the logs:

---

2022-06-03T03:43:22.170878337Z ASP .NETCore Version: 6.0.3

2022-06-03T03:43:22.170881637Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted

2022-06-03T03:43:22.462209593Z Running oryx create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -defaultAppFilePath /defaulthome/hostingstart/hostingstart.dll     -bindPort 8080 -userStartupCommand 'dotnet PermanentRedirectMinimal.dll'

2022-06-03T03:43:22.553430350Z Cound not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'

2022-06-03T03:43:22.553445850Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...

2022-06-03T03:43:22.553843654Z Build Operation ID: [guid]

2022-06-03T03:43:23.236717018Z

2022-06-03T03:43:23.237393225Z Agent extension

2022-06-03T03:43:23.237407225Z Before if loop >> DotNet Runtime

2022-06-03T03:43:23.277833149Z DotNet Runtime 6.0Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'

2022-06-03T03:43:23.358910299Z Running user provided startup command...

2022-06-03T03:43:25.470314040Z Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.

2022-06-03T03:43:25.470359841Z To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.

2022-06-03T03:43:25.470366541Z For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.

2022-06-03T03:43:25.470370941Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)

2022-06-03T03:43:25.470375241Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions)

2022-06-03T03:43:25.470379341Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

2022-06-03T03:43:25.470383541Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IEnumerable`1 listenOptions, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

2022-06-03T03:43:25.470387541Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

2022-06-03T03:43:25.470402041Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

2022-06-03T03:43:25.470405941Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

2022-06-03T03:43:25.470409541Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

2022-06-03T03:43:25.470413041Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)

2022-06-03T03:43:25.470416641Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)

2022-06-03T03:43:25.470426442Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)

2022-06-03T03:43:25.470430142Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.Run(String url)

2022-06-03T03:43:25.472178560Z    at Program.$(String[] args) in e:...\PermanentRedirectMinimal\Program.cs:line 22 [ ==> where app.Run() is ]

2022-06-03T03:43:41.244915770Z Could not open output /home/logs/dumps/coredump.d26e6752ab2d.36.1654227802: 2 No such file or directory

2022-06-03T03:43:41.253765645Z Gathering state for process 36 dotnet

2022-06-03T03:43:41.253793945Z Crashing thread 00000024 signal 00000006

2022-06-03T03:43:41.253799545Z Writing minidump with heap to file /home/logs/dumps/coredump.d26e6752ab2d.36.1654227802

2022-06-03T03:43:41.762563322Z /opt/startup/startup.sh: line 10:    36 Aborted                 (core dumped) dotnet PermanentRedirectMinimal.dll

2022-06-03T03:43:42.474Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container annuaire_0_4715a3e4. Elapsed time = 19.6895811 sec

2022-06-03T03:43:42.508Z ERROR - Container blah_0_4715a3e4 for site blah has exited, failing site start

2022-06-03T03:43:42.511Z ERROR - Container blah_0_4715a3e4 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

2022-06-03T03:43:42.520Z INFO  - Stopping site blah because it failed during startup.

---

Comment: According to the error prompt, during startup, an error was encountered when looking for the certificate to configure HTTPS. [Please refer to this blog and try to load the certificate](https://ankitvijay.net/2021/04/14/certificate-azure-app-service-linux/). Any progress can be updated in the post, we can help you in time.

Comment: I use App Service **Managed** certificate. You can't upload it.

Comment: What kind of app service plan you use? Free? or Standard ?

Comment: B1, and I think it should work perfectly fine

Comment: The free App Service Managed Certificate (ASMC) comes with a few limitations. ASMC does not support wildcard certificates.


Must have CNAME mapped directly to <app-name>.azurewebsites.net. Mapping to an intermediate CNAME value will block certificate issuance and renewal.

Also note that the free certificate is issued by DigiCert. For some top-level domains, you must explicitly allow DigiCert as a certificate issuer by creating a `CAA domain record` with the value: 0 issue `digicert.com`.

Comment: As for as "didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start" - App Service  custom container listens on port 80 (default), Kindly confirm the listening port for the app. If your container listens to a different port, set the WEBSITES_PORT app setting in your App Service app. [doc][https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#configure-port-number]

[How does the container warmup request work?][https://learn.microsoft.com/troubleshoot/azure/general/faqs-app-service-linux#how-do-i-specify-port-in-my-linux-container-]

Comment: why not doing the redirect using DNS records ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed by Azure Support, this scenario is not supported for Linux App Service. :( Azure power.

Comment: Which part, wildcard subdomains or just the redirect in general? Does it work on Windows?